# Should questions with sexual topics even be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/302/what-really-happened-in-the-end-of-the-grapes-of-wrath) recent question deals with a sexual topic, and I'm wondering whether these (embarrassing?) questions should even be allowed. Of course Literature is full of this sort of topic, but should we let questions like these on the site?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/are-questions-about-a-slightly-adult-scifi-comic-acceptable) and [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/should-questions-about-sex-and-other-adult-activities-be-off-topic/3047#3047)

Comment: What do you want to do? Ban Lady Chatterley's Lover?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/163/do-we-need-want-any-sorts-of-content-warnings)

Answer (score 19):

I don't see a reason against such topics. On Stack Exchange, folks are expected to behave maturely, and that involves covering topics that - well, require some maturity to handle. For the same reason, I don't think we should avoid works about, say, violence, war or drugs.

I think that we'll see questions that cover these topics tangentially, and we may even see questions regarding erotica. That still qualifies as literature, though (I think), and it doesn't seem right to exclude it just because it's not necessarily a subject you'd bring up at the dinner table.

It's true that these questions may be disturbing or embarrassing to some. I totally understand and sympathize with that. But I don't think it's a reason to throw a blanket ban on them.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to quote from a [Worldbuilding answer](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/about-children-and-sex) by the user [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green) to a meta question similar to this one because it almost perfectly sums up my thoughts on the situation.

> Our world contains all these topics, as sad/unfortunate as that may
> be. Writing stories is a way to grapple with those topics.
>
> I don't have a problem with questions on any of these topics as long
> as they are conveyed in a dispassionate, clinical tone. Doctors learn
> to judiciously look at the most private parts of the human body as
> something to work on, not as a sexual object. I choose to believe that...[scholars of literature]...come here with the hope of this kind of dispassionate analysis
> for their questions. I'm willing to meet them on those terms on the
> vast majority of topics.
>
> Advocating violence, rape, mass-murdering or anything else...is completely unacceptable and I would instantly downvote/report/flag any question or answer that did advocate this. Similarly, I don't want to read long graphic descriptions of these sensitive topics. Talking about how to execute 20 million people is one thing. Saying that it's something that should be done in the real world is something completely different.